# Defining operators that work on multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframes: `pd1` and `pd2`

```
pd1 = 
       A      B      C
1  hello    foo  hello
2    foo    bar  hello
3  world    bar  world
4  world    bar  world
```

and

```
pd2 = 

   A  B  C
1  8  0  3
2  8  5  2
3  4  7  0
4  4  1  3
```

and say that I want to do something like creating a third dataframe with the following result

```
       A         B      C
1  hello;8    foo;0  hello;3
2    foo;8    bar;5  hello;2
3  world;4    bar;7  world;2
4  world;4    bar;1  world;0
```

While I could loop through every location, index both dataframes and concatenate the result in a third dataframe, I was wondering if I can do better.

Reading about [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) I wondered if there is a similar way of defining and applying operators that work on pairs of dataframes. For example, for the problem above I could define the following operator:

```
def f(x,y):    
    return str(x)  + ';' + str(y)
```

where `f(x,y)` is a function that operates element-wise.

This idea could be extended to multiple dataframes (more than 2). Is there anything in Pandas that support the definition of such multi-dataframe operators?

Comment: To the downvoter, could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

You can already do this, just stringify with applymap; the '+' concatenates

```
In [14]: df1.applymap(str) + df2.applymap(lambda x: ';%s' % x)
Out[14]: 
     A
0  0;0
1  1;2
2  2;4
3  3;6
4  4;8
```

Prob not very efficient, maybe you should just create the columns you want then to_csv with a sep of ';'?

Comment: I guess the generalization would be something like `pd.DataFrame.add(*[df.applymap(str)+';' for df in dfs]).applymap(lambda x: x[:-1])`?

Comment: I think you might have to do it iteratively with the expansion, something like ``x = dfs[0]; for df in dfs[1:]: x += df``, because ``.add`` only accepts binary